# Importing spooled Oracle data into Excel : how to pivot the rows/columns of the resulting table

Tags: oracle, excel, sqlplus

A select on a table in Oracle is spooled to a text file, the text file resembles the following:

```
PRIV | jan-2013 | 1
PART | feb-2013 | 5
PRIV | feb-2013 | 3
PART | jan-2013 | 2
```

This file is then imported into Excel (using "|" as the delimitor etc.).

However, I am unable to produce the column chart I wish with this format.

To achieve the desired column chart, it would require a table as follows:

```
       jan-2013 feb-2013
PRIV      1       3
PART      2       5
```

How can I realise this type of table from my Oracle select so that the import file would be in the desired format for Excel?

Or is  possible within Excel to alter the format of the original table to achieve the desired table? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do quite easily with a Pivot Table:

1. Insert->Pivot Table->Select your data table
2. On the right, you'll see a field for each column of your data. Pull the first column (with  PRIV and PART) to the Row labels field
3. Pull the second column with the months to the column labels field
4. Pull the third column with the data to the Values field.

Done! :-)